# implementation of shrink_to_fit for string and vector are different?

Tags: c++

I called `shrink_to_fit()` for vector and it reduced the capacity to number of elements  in vector but when I used  `shrink_to_fit()` for string , it reduced the size but its not the number of elements in string .

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   vector<char> v1;
   v1.reserve(20);
   v1.push_back('a');
   v1.push_back('b');
   cout << " vector capacity= "<<v1.capacity() <<endl;
   v1.shrink_to_fit();
   cout << " changed vector capacity= "<<v1.capacity() <<endl;

   string s1;
   s1.reserve(20);
   s1.push_back('a');
   s1.push_back('b');
   cout <<" string capacity = " << s1.capacity() <<endl;
   s1.shrink_to_fit();
   cout <<" changed string capacity = " << s1.capacity() <<endl;

}
```

OUTPUT :

```
  vector capacity= 20
  changed vector capacity= 2
  string capacity = 30
  changed string capacity = 15
```

Comment: Can't confirm but it looks like what you are seeing is that the string employees short string optimization and it can hold 15 characters before it would have to allocate storage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modern implementations of `std::string` generally provide "short string optimization", which means that strings under a certain length don't require a separate allocation, but are stored inside the `std::string` object itself (typically in the space that would be used for some of the pointers). So, this means that you cannot get less capacity than - in your case - 15 (which rings right, as that's 16 with the NUL terminator, and that's two 64 bit pointers), as it's stored straight in the string object, when there's no longer anything else to deallocate.

Besides, you are comparing apples to oranges; <del>nothing stops `std::vector` from implementing a similar optimization *for smaller types*</del>¹, but you are comparing a `std::vector<int>` (whose elements are generally 4 bytes, so only 4 would fit in the aforementioned 16 bytes) with a `std::string` (whose elements are 1-byte `char`). A more proper comparison would be against `std::vector<char>`.

---

1. actually, as pointed out in the comments, the current standard places requirements incompatible with such an optimization; still, the main point stands: when comparing two containers, you should do so making sure that the "boundary conditions" are the same, so you can spot the actual implementation differences (`std::string` does SSO, `std::vector<char>` doesn't) without being distracted by differences that arise from the fact that you are comparing them against different problems.

Comment: I edited it to vector<char> and it shows the same result.

Comment: It would probably still be a legal vector implementation, just one that hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: @zneak No it isn't, because swapping vectors must not invalidate the iterators. Some consider this a flaw in the standard, but it is what it is. Boost has vectors that provide the optimization, if you need it.

Comment: I appreciate the correction. I will still make the point that "thing X doesn't implement Y" is generally not a good proof that "thing X couldn't implement Y in the future".

Comment: @zneak It cannot implement Y unless the standard is changed in a breaking way. Considering we are talking about `std::vector` here, I find that unlikely. But well, who knows, maybe some day...

Comment: I believe you. My comment is that when you expand your horizon beyond the very narrow case of `std::vector`, extrapolating that an assertion is universally false because you found it to be false on one implementation will often be incorrect. If OP had used an `std::string` implementation from the 32-bit era to test whether the short string optimization was legal (instead of using an `std::vector` implementation from a recent implementation), they would likely have found the wrong answer.

Comment: Btw, the size of `std::string` and `std::vector` is usually 24; 8 bytes each for capacity, size and the data pointer. You can indeed cram 23 chars in SSO, but gcc implements SSO differently, probably reserving one of the three variables mentioned above for the current size or something.